# How do I insert data to mySQL using HTML Select tag?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using HTML and php to insert data into MySql from a text field and select tag but the data from select tag inserts zero. What am I missing?

```html
<input type="text" size="30" name="appid" maxlength="8" placeholder="ID Number..."</>
<select name="appamount">
   <option value = "1000"> 1000 </option>
   <option value = "2000"> 2000 </option>
</select>
  
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
```

```
    $Your_Name = ($_POST["apppname"]);
$Your_Amount = ($_POST["appamount"]);

{
    $mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO sample.details (name, amount) VALUES ('$Your_Name', '$Your_Amount')";  

    if ($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) 
    {
        echo "<h1>Request Received. </p>
```

Comment: Your question is missing the PHP code you use to insert a row in MySQL, can you add it?

Comment: share your php code also ?

Comment: The data from the text field is inserting, I just have a problem with the select tag.

Comment: Try `var_dump($Your_Amount);`, directly after you define that variable, to see what is inside that variable.